# B2C account error page-redirect to home/error

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to customize the account error for the Azure B2C application error(AADB2C99002), however, it always redirects to https:///MicrosoftIdentity/Account/Error, while my account error page should be https:///Home/Error
I tried this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-6.0#exception-handler-page),and disables the development mode, but nothing works. please advise.
[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGiZI.jpg)

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });
    }
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this as we're experiencing the same thing.  Appreciate any help that you can give if you have.

Comment: I'll try a url rewrite rule and post the resuls once I've given it a whirl.